# Replace ::after with actual element

Tags: css

I have this CSS declaration here for `.checkbox--styled::after`. My question is: if all this does is add an element after the `.checkbox--styled` elements in the DOM, why can't I replace this to `.checkbox--styled--after` and add a tag `<span class="checkbox--styled--after"></span>` and get the same results?

```
.checkbox--styled::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: initial;
  transition-property: transform;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2Cellipse%2Cline%2Cpath%2Cpolygon%2Cpolyline%2Crect%2Ctext%7Bfill%3A%23479ccf%20%21important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M23.6%205L22%203.4c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L8.5%2015l-4.8-4.7c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L.3%2011.9c-.5.4-.5%201.2%200%201.6l7.3%207.1c.5.4%201.2.4%201.7%200l14.3-14c.5-.4.5-1.1%200-1.6z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bLwa2s05/1/

Comment: Can you please create  fiddle?

Comment: "why can't I replace this to `.checkbox--styled--after`" - is there anything in particular stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @SunilGehlot I'd like to rebuild this without the `::after` psudo element, possible?  https://jsfiddle.net/bLwa2s05/1/

Comment: @ThomasReggi Sorry but am afraid, i can't do that with css without after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of-course you can replace pseudo-elements with real elements. It is actually a very straight-forward thing to do. For `::before` elements, insert the real element before any content inside parent and for the `::after` elements, insert it after all content (just before the end tag).

But for the check-effect to work properly, the **below selectors need to be changed**. These selectors need to be changed because these are the two selectors that are producing the checkbox animation.

```css
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox--styled::after 
.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox--styled::after
```

**to**

```css
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox--styled .checkbox--styled--after 
.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox--styled .checkbox--styled--after
```

```css
* {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.checkbox--container {
  position: relative
}
.radio,
.checkbox,
.radio--styled,
.checkbox--styled {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-right-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-left-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkbox--styled {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.checkbox--styled--after {
  /*content: ''; -- This is not required for real elements but it does no harm when the real element has no content */
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position-x: 50%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: initial;
  transition-property: transform;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2Cellipse%2Cline%2Cpath%2Cpolygon%2Cpolyline%2Crect%2Ctext%7Bfill%3A%23479ccf%20%21important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M23.6%205L22%203.4c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L8.5%2015l-4.8-4.7c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L.3%2011.9c-.5.4-.5%201.2%200%201.6l7.3%207.1c.5.4%201.2.4%201.7%200l14.3-14c.5-.4.5-1.1%200-1.6z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
.checkbox:active ~ .checkbox--styled,
.checkbox:focus ~ .checkbox--styled {
  border-top-color: #479ccf;
  border-right-color: #479ccf;
  border-bottom-color: #479ccf;
  border-left-color: #479ccf;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox--styled .checkbox--styled--after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox--styled .checkbox--styled--after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2012%2012%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2012%2012%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2Cellipse%2Cline%2Cpath%2Cpolygon%2Cpolyline%2Crect%2Ctext%7Bfill%3A%23479ccf%20%21important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M6%200%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M.8%207C.3%207%200%206.7%200%206.2v-.4c0-.5.3-.8.8-.8h10.5c.4%200%20.7.3.7.8v.5c0%20.4-.3.7-.8.7H.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
li,
form,
input {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
input {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
input,
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-right-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-bottom-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-left-color: rgb(211, 219, 226);
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
.radio,
.checkbox {
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-top-width: initial;
  border-right-width: initial;
  border-bottom-width: initial;
  border-left-width: initial;
  border-top-color: initial;
  border-right-color: initial;
  border-bottom-color: initial;
  border-left-color: initial;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox--container">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <span class="checkbox--styled">
    <span class='checkbox--styled--after'>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

**Changing them to be like below would not work** because the `.checkbox--styled--after` element is not a direct sibling of the checkbox. So, it should be selected by first referencing the parent element which is a sibling of the checkbox.

```css
.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox--styled--after 
.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox--styled--after
```

Answer (score 2):

:: is for calling Pseudo-Elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp
"The ::after selector inserts something after the content of each selected element(s)."

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp
For your answer I have to say it doesn't work because "The content property (that you have used on line 2 of this css) is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, to insert generated content."

Answer (score 0):

The ::after css rule is what is creating that fancy animation on the checkbox, and this has been done this way just to avoid creating more elements in the html markup. It keeps simple your html at the cost of a quite elaborated css set of rules.

Of course you could create additional elements in your html widget and do as you say, but you'll have to carry a larger html structure everywhere you want to use the checkbox. There's no problem on that, and is up to you.

In my opinion this is a nice featured css exercise.

Comment: I understand and 100% agree, but I'm abstracting that HTML out in a React component so it' will always be easy to carry around as `<Checkbox/>` and I'd really like to set the SVG color dynamically. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104248/dynamic-css-via-prop-using-cssmodules-with-react-component